# Write JDBC Request results to CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I want to generate dynamic HTTP Requests for different URL paths with credentials. For that I need to fetch the URLs from a database, so I have created one JDBC Connection Configuration and set JDBC Request(Pre-Processors) with my Select statement.

Now I need to write the output of my select statement to a CSV data file. Can I do that or do I have to loop through this controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as follows

1. Define "Result Variable Name" like `resultSet` (you can use anything meaningful here)

   [image: JDBC Result Variable Name]
2. Add JSR223 PreProcessor to your test plan (just make sure it is located **below** the JDBC PreProcessor)
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   resultSet = vars.getObject("resultSet")
   result = new StringBuilder()

   for (Object row : resultSet ) {
       iter = row.entrySet().iterator()
       while (iter.hasNext()) {
           pair = iter.next()
           result.append(pair.getValue())
           result.append(",")
       }
       result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
   }

   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("foo.csv"), result.toString(), "UTF-8")
   ```

If everything goes well you should see `foo.txt` in JMeter's "bin" folder, the file will contain your SQL query output data in CSV format.

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more information on how to work with JDBC test elements results in JMeter tests.